# Downloading a large file in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a react web app which lets you download files stored in the database as base64 strings.

Everything works fine until you try downloading a 120mb file.
Here's the C# code:

```
var document = await _context.documents.FromSqlRaw($"select base64string, filename from documents where primary_key = {150}")
         .FirstAsync();
```

This is the class:

```
[Keyless]
public class Document
{
    public string base64string { get; set; } = "";
    public string filename { get; set; } = "";

}
```

Has anyone ever encountered this problem before?

Thanks

Comment: My guess would be some timeout. I would probably not recommend storing large files directly in the database, there are arguments either way, but as files sizes increases is becomes more advantageous to store references to files on disk.

Comment: @JustMe: What exactly problem did you face? Did you receive some error message?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @JonasH this is unfortunately not a choice

Comment: @Victor No error messages, I tried with a 10mb file, it takes about 30 seconds while with an sql query it takes less than a second to get the file

Comment: @jarlh Sql Server, it's not a dbms problem though, I tried with another app running with the same database and the file downloads without a problem

Comment: @JonasH also not a timeout problem as the query takes 1 seconds on Sql Server... I'm completely stuck

Comment: @JustMe: You can try to use [Response compression in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1). Perhaps this will speed up the process.

Comment: Why is it keyless? Is there no indexing applied? Where is the {primary_key} defined? There is a lot of missing information to determine the cause of performance issues. Have you tried debugging and checking where it gets stuck?

Comment: @HamsterWithPitchfork it's keyless cause I'm mapping a stored procedure result. I found that the only solution was to open a new connection every time, I can't use the _context to make such a call, still don't know why though.

Answer (score 0):

your database connection seems to be timing out
You can change the connection string like this

{string connectionString = "Server=testServer;Database=Testdb;User Id=TestUser;Password=*****;Connection Timeout=90"}

Comment: doesn't change anything, I don't think it's the connection string as it takes less than a seconds on Sql Server. It takes forever only with EF Core.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).